# Links inside JsTree treeview not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview, jstree

I have a treeview with tables in the lowest nodes. The tables have certain links in them, but the links dont redirect to the page they should. The link address is visible in bottom of the browser but the links dont call the ActionMethod they should call (they dont call them at all).
The who tree has a lot of data so I am posting a short example of how the bigger tree looks.

```
<div id="tree">
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2
        <ul>
            <li>inner item1 
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Hello</th>
                        <th><a href="~/Views/home/ActivatePage">link</a></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Hello</th>
                        <th><a href="~/Views/home/ActivatePage">link</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>aa</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

Any clue why this might happen, because the links work when i paste them into the browser field.
[image: Link is visible when I hover over the first link in the table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jstree select_node prevent to nevigate. try this

```
    $('body').on('click','a',function(){
window.location=$(this).attr('href');
});
```

or

```
    $('#tree').on('click','a',function(){
window.location=$(this).attr('href');
});
```

[check at](http://jsfiddle.net/rajumjib/9jkav03s/)